# zoo time series loses colname information after reducing a multivariate to a univariate time series

Tags: r, zoo

Let's say we have the following multivariate time series

```
A=zoo(data.frame(x=100:101,y=200:201,z=300:301),1:2)
```

Everything is fine with `colnames(A)` here. The function gives

```
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Now select a specific date of the time series

```
B=A[1,]
```

`colnames(B)` gives the same result as above. So, everything is still fine.

Let's further reduce the time series by

```
C=B[,abs(B)>=300]
```

In this case, `colnames(C)` returns `NULL`. That is, the column name information `z` is lost.

Any pointers to how to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `drop=FALSE`:

```
C=B[,abs(B)>=300,drop=FALSE]
```